# MVC3 linq joins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, join

As a novice am trying my hands on MVC3,razor, EF I have Three  connected Tables that I want to produce a view from it. In a simpleton's brief the following are about the tables

PJUsers - ID, memUID(this unique Id from membership),FirstName,LastName

PJAwards - user nominates another user for an award, this links with awardtypesID as foreign key ( awardId,bool:awardok)

PJAwartypes - (awardtypeID, awardName)

The query in the controller is like this

```
    var lists =
from tl in db.PJawards
join u in db.PJUsers on tl.nomineeId equals u.ID into tl_u
join i in db.PJUsers on tl.nominatorId equals i.MemUID into tl_i
where tl.awardOk 
orderby tl.awardDated ascending

from u in tl_u.DefaultIfEmpty()
from i in tl_i.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
   Status = tl.awardOk,
    nomineeFname = u.FirstName,
    nomineeLname = u.LastName,
    award =  tl.PJawards.awardName,
    Dated = tl.awardDated,
    nominatorFname = i.FirstName,
    nominatorLname = i.LastName,
    nomineeCountry = u.Citizen,
    nomineeResidence = u.Residence,
    awardtypeId = tl.ID
};
```

somewhere i read that i have to construct a model class similar to the query in the controller

```
{
public class AwardUserInfo
{
    public AwardUserInfo() { }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string nomineeFname { get; set; }
    public string nomineeLname { get; set; }
    public string award { get; set; }
    public string Dated { get; set; }
    public string nominatorFname { get; set; }
    public string nominatorLname { get; set; }
    public string nomineeCountry { get; set; }
    public string nomineeResidence { get; set; }
    public int awardtypeId { get; set; }

}
}
```

Please I learn by examples so  to be able to help me assume I don't know anything

Comment: Don't use joins. If Your EF model is ok You can manage without them (c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> somewhere i read that i have to construct a model class similar to the query in the controller

Try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel).

I guess your ef-model is similar to 
[image]

So You can create a ViewModel class

```
public class PJAwardsViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NominatorFName { get; set; }
    public string NomineeFname { get; set; }
    public string AwardName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAwarded { get; set; }
}
```

It will be also good if You add some service class

```
public class PJAwardsService
{
    public static List<PJAwards> GetAll()
    {
        using (var context = new YourDBEntities())
        {
            return context.PJAwards
                .Include(x => x.PJUsers)
                .Include(x => x.PJUsers1)
                .Include(x => x.PJAwartypes).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

(Don't forget to write `using System.Data.Entity;` )

Then You can add a ViewModelHelper class

```
public class PJAwardsViewModelHelper
{
    public static PJAwardsViewModel PopulatePJAwardsViewModel(PJAwards pjaward)
    {
        return new PJAwardsViewModel
        {
            Id = pjaward.Id,
            NominatorFName = pjaward.PJUsers.FirstName,
            NomineeFname = pjaward.PJUsers1.FirstName,
            AwardName = pjaward.PJAwartypes.AwardName,
            IsAwarded = pjaward.IsAwarded
        };
    }

    public static List<PJAwardsViewModel> PopulatePJAwardsViewModelList(List<PJAwards> pjawardsList)
    {
        return pjawardsList.Select(x => PopulatePJAwardsViewModel(x)).ToList();
    }
}
```

At the end Your controller index method will look like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var pjawards = PJAwardsViewModelHelper.PopulatePJAwardsViewModelList(PJAwardsService.GetAll().ToList());
    return View(pjawards);
}
```

The only thing You should do is add a view (build the project before). Choose `PJAwardsViewModel` as a `Model class` and `List` as a `scaffold template`.
Enjoy it.

Comment: Thanks to you @Shymep very much that is very detailed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step guide by Steven Sanderson on how to use Asp.net MVC3, EF Code First with MVCScaffolding (powershell automation).

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

It is a multipart blog post takes you through the exciting journey of MVC3.

All the best.

Comment: Thanks @Prafulla I realised I was very close to it and your link helped me understand what to do